# what does (0+n)/n mean in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I am new to pyspark. I noticed that when I run my code in jupyter it shows something like this: (0 + n) / n
when n equals 1, code is running much faster. So my question is what can I do to make it small?
for example, now I am running a code and n equals 8 and it takes forever to run the code.

for example, now I am running a code and n equals 8 and it takes forever to run the code.

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data and your running code ?

Comment: @AmirHosseinShahdaei my data is about traffic in city. It involves camera code and date an hour and plate number of cars which were seen by that camera. I want to perform LSH for cosine distance.

Comment: @AmirHosseinShahdaei my main problem is groupbykey. I waited for 4 hours. but it didn't work. and the strange thing is that It does not give any error.

Comment: @AmirHosseinShahdaei is it possible that I can send my jupyter notebook to you?

Comment: Hey Mohammad, It's better to share your problematic code cell and an example of your data (maybe 5 rows) here so anybody could answer your question or if anyone has the same problem as you find your question easier